# AWS VPC Cannot delete routing rule to inexistent IP range

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, routetable

I've been looking into this all morning but it seems to be beyond my knowledge about AWS VPCs.

We have and old AWS account with a series of VPCs in it. These were created years ago. The VPC I'm concerned about can easily be 6 years old if not older. The existing VPCs are:

`eu-west-1` (Ireland)

- **I1: `172.31.0.0/16`**
- I2: `172.102.0.0/16`
- I3: `172.201.0.0/16`
- I4: `192.168.96.0/20`

`us-west-2` (Oregon)

- O1: `192.168.0.144/20`

The VPC I'm working with is **I1: `172.31.0.0/16`**.

`I1` and `O1` Are peered.

Right, I now have a new account where I've created a new VPC in Oregon.  Let's call it

- NO1: `10.1.0.0/20`

I have peered `O1` and `NO1`. Peering works fine and the route tables do too.

The issue comes when I peered `I1` and `NO1`.

- Creating the peered connection was fine.
- Adding rules to the `NO1` route table worked fine.

My concern is the following: when I go to modify the route table for `I1` I see the following rules.

- `172.31.0.0/16` `local` `active` (that's the IP range set for this VPC, expected)
- `10.0.0.0/8` `local` `active` (This is my issue)
- `0.0.0.0/0` `inet` `active`
- Some other existing rules...

I don't understand the `10.0.0.0/8` rule. The full IP range is being routed internally and:

- That's not within the IP range of the VPC
- just in case I was missing something I checked all the VPCs and subnets I could find. There's nothing with that IP range.

When I went to modify the route table the `172.31.0.0/16` and the `10.0.0.0/8` rules cannot be deleted so I can only assume they were created by default.

My question is, how can this rule be `active` when the IP range is "non-existent"? Why I cannot delete this? I've never seen this range being added by default to a route table, is this something maybe AWS used to do ages ago?

I've added a rule `10.1.0.0/20` routing traffic to my peered VPC. I'm hoping since it's more specific it will work fine. Am I right to think that?

Comment: @Carlos Robles I don't believe the details you have removed are that "anecdotal". I did not create the VPCs so I have no more information about then than what I have given. I think it's better to clarify that from the beginning and not waste anyone's time. They were created possibly 6 years ago, which might mean VPCs were different back then. I believe that to also be relevant to my question.

Comment: Im happy to add it back. I believe the question is big so trimming things out helps getting more readers. I will add now again

Comment: If you aren't able to resolve this, it might be worth a support ticket to AWS (and maybe leverage Developer or higher support plan).

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this will cause us any actual problems but would like to know why that rule is there and why it cannot be deleted.  I'll wait for a few days before contacting AWS support. My interactions with them have been less than satisfactory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have ClassicLink (network connectivity between VPC and EC2-Classic) enabled for this VPC.  Turn it off (after  verifying that you aren't actually using it, of course) and that route will remove itself.

> When you enable a VPC for ClassicLink, a static route is added to all of the VPC route tables with a destination of `10.0.0.0/8` and a target of `local`. This allows communication between instances in the VPC and any EC2-Classic instances that are then linked to the VPC. If you add a custom route table to a ClassicLink-enabled VPC, a static route is automatically added with a destination of `10.0.0.0/8` and a target of `local`. When you disable ClassicLink for a VPC, this route is automatically deleted in all of the VPC route tables.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/vpc-classiclink.html

Comment: That's great, thank you! I'll look into it. Makes total sense as some of the instances and DBs were created many years ago. Some of then have been up for 5 or 6 years.

Answer (score -1):

This route can be perfectly because of the peering.

- Note that the CIDR range `10.0.0.0/8` actually includes `10.0.0.1` to `10.255.255.254`
- Your `NO1`, `10.1.0.0/20` includes IPs `10.1.0.1` to `10.1.15.254`
- So actually `10.1.0.0/20` is inside of `10.0.0.0/8`

It looks like what AWS is doing is blocking the range that you need and a bit more, in the `I1` route table, maybe to avoid overlapping or for any other reason. But definitely `10.1.0.0/20` is inside of `10.0.0.0/8`

To deal with this thing of IP ranges I use this tool that is quite ilustrative https://cidr.xyz/, it helps understanding for an CIDR range what is the minimum and maximum IPs and the total possible different IPs that can help also defining subnets.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. However, None of the other VPCs I've peered has done that. I need to add the routing rule by hand. And to be honest, that rule is not blocking "the range I need and a bit more"... I'm using 4096 addresses, that rule is blocking 16.7M. A little bit over the top if that was the case...

Comment: but you are saying that doesn't let you delete it. It cannot be deleted because it includes the peered range. 

About why is so big I dont have a clue. But deleting it wont be possible. 

Out of curiosity, what happens if you try to reduce the range to exactly, or something nearer to what you need?

Comment: We agree it includes the peering range, but that rule was there before I added the peering. And it's still there now that I've removed it. Also, other VPCs peered with that one don't include that rule. Check the screenshot.
I1: The peering rule is in line 4, which I added manually. The blanket rule seems to be there added by default, along with the correct CIDR for that VPC.
O1: The peering rule is in line 3, which I added manually. The only default rule is the VPC's CIDR.

https://imgur.com/a/c5Ug8qh